# Is there a way to drop values from only one variable?

Tags: stata

I want to split 100 observations in Stata into 2 sets of 50 and drop all missing values so used

```
gen A = x if _n <= 50
gen B = x if _n > 50
```

How do I remove the missing values from each variable  without affecting the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do that and you don’t need to, as Stata generally ignores missing values.

You can `drop` entire observations (rows in spreadsheet jargon) or entire variables (columns ditto) but the equivalent for some values in a variable is just setting values to missing, which you have done.

The question in return is why you want to do this.